# Custom Desktop Web App vs Node Framework

Tags: web-applications, electron, nw.js

What are the benefits of using a NodeJS based web app framework (Electron, NWjs) over a custom web application run locally, like Python and Bottle? A lot of people seem to be concerned with protecting their "server" side JS code, but why not just use a compiled web framework (Go, Java, Cpp) run locally and launch the browser on startup, then serve up the content locally?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question, also experienced both examples. but both sides have an advantaje.

A locally web app can be accessed for everyone on the network in any type of device. and obviously doesn't require an installation. (All this is pretyy obvious)

But an aplication based on Electron or NWjs can do more things, since they use the commandline, read, update or create files, and maybe a lot of things more than that.

But they need to be installed, this can be useful if you want to protect your resources from someone on the network. Also you can build apps cross-platform without problems.